# Echo values from two foreach arrays without duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, echo, glob

I have this two arrays:

```
$files=glob("filepath/folder/*.*);
$thumbs=glob("filepath/folder/thumbs/*.*);
```

Main folder called in `$files` gets the full resolution images, while thumb has thumbnails for faster page loading, so it does not need to load the big images and resize them.

But my problem is now how to echo these two loops out?
I've tried nested foreach loops like

```
foreach ($files as $fl){
    foreach ($thumbs as $tb) {
        echo '<a href="<?=$fl?>"><img src="<?=$tb?>"></a>';
    }
}
```

But this makes duplicates because it echoes for each element in files and for each in thumbs.

How can I echo them without duplicating?

Comment: Have you any naming "system" to associate full resolution filenames and thumbnail filenames?

Comment: You can enumerate only one directory (let's say the thumbnails) then, for each image, check if the corresponding file exists in the other directory. Only then put them on the page.

Comment: Your assignment `$thumb` is singular, your usage is plural `$thumbs`. I'd suggest setting all file data to a single array, so you have each file's data in one sub array, and loop each one. eg indexes of "file1"=> array "file",  "thumbnail" etc. You can then easily check each file array has all the required data. As it is, there's chance the arrays might have different number of indexes and thus fail to map (eg a file is present but missing thumbnail). Also see the manual which has examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Syscall they have the same name. Image1.jpg is in the folder, Image1.jpg is in the thumbs, only difference is size. 
@axiac interesting, how can I do that?
James: that was just a typo, sorry, they are named the same.

Comment: Use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php), [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)/[`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help, this worked

```
    $len = max(count($files), count($thumbs));
for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
    $fl = isset($files[$i]) ? $files[$i] : '';
    $tb = isset($thumbs[$i]) ? $thumbs[$i] : '';
    echo <a href="<?=$fl?>"><img src="<?=$tb?>"></a>;
}
```